# Explanation for the size of structs in C?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

So I'm looking at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student {
    int id;
    char name[32];
} s, *sp;

int main() {
    printf("sizeof(structStudent) = %u\n", sizeof(structStudent));
    printf("sizeof(s) = %u\n", sizeof(s));
    printf("sizeof(structStudent*) = %u\n", sizeof(structStudent*));
    printf("sizeof(sp) = %u\n", sizeof(sp));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
sizeof(struct Student) = 36
sizeof(s) = 36
sizeof(struct Student*) = 4
sizeof(sp) = 4
```

Why is the size of `struct Student*` 4 and why is the size of `sp` also 4? My powerpoint does not elaborate on this. I know why the size of `struct Student` and `s` is 36: because 32 `char` bytes+4 bytes(for one `int`)=36 total.

Comment: That doesn't even compile.

Comment: The ones of size 4 are pointers on your 32-bit system.

Comment: `sp` has type `struct student *`, so those two things report the same size

Comment: 'The output is...'...? What output? Tha code presented does not compile, so how can it produce any output?

Comment: @CiaPan it's similar to `intmain`

Comment: "Why is the size of `struct Student*` 4?" - Questions like this are like "why is 2+2 equal 4?" Why are you asking this question? Why do you find it unusual that size of `struct Student*` is 4? Until you explain this, it is not possible to determine the root of your confusion and not possible to address that root.

Comment: And yet, AnT is right - this is such an integral part of C that the lack of this knowledge is going to hinder your ability to ever do anything with it.

Comment: To be honest, KevinDTimm is absolutely right, as well as AnT is. Go read some basic intro to C programming, they will certainly have a section about built-in data types, their sizes and layouts. This is truly a *very basic* knowledge for a programmer, and without that you'll be unable to write any useful program (I mean writing programs by yourself, not just copying and modifying examples or excerpts from others' code)..

Comment: Curious: Why did you use `"%u"` with `sizeof(structStudent)` versus any other specifiers like `"%d"`, `"%lu"`, or `"%zu"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your platform, simple pointers occupy 32 bits. That's basically the definition of a 32-bit platform.

The address of the White House doesn't have to be longer than my address just because the White House is bigger than my house.

Answer (score 5):

`struct Student *` is a *pointer* and it doesn't contain almost any data, it's merely a pointer. But pointers are stored somewhere and take some space, 4 bytes in your case.

`struct Student`, however, is a fully-featured struct that occupies as much space as you've calculated (the array and the `id` take their space).